# Get time in milliseconds without an installing an extra package?

Tags: linux, perl, time, package, milliseconds

How can I get the time in milliseconds in Perl without installing any extra package?

I am running Linux.

Comment: `date +%N` gives you nanoseconds... you can work from there? %s gives seconds sinds 1970...

Comment: Any reason you can't use `Time::HiRes`?

Comment: Why can't you install a module?  Regardless, depending on your version of Perl, you probably have Time::HiRes (http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) available.

Comment: `date +%N` works on Linux but not AIX... (sad day)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Time::HiRes` has been part of the core since Perl 5.7.3. To check for its availability, check for the Perl version, `perl -v`, or try to use it with `perl -e 'use Time::HiRes;'`, both from the command line.

Sample usage:

```
use Time::HiRes qw/ time sleep /;

my $start = time;
sleep rand(10)/3;
my $end   = time;

print 'Slept for ', ( $end - $start ) , "\n";
```

To build on Konerak's comment, if it isn't there or it cannot be used, use native Linux commands via backticks:

```
sub time_since_epoch { return `date +%s.%N` }

print time_since_epoch;
```

Comment: To load and/or verify a module from the command line you can use:

    perl -MTime::HiRes -e 1

in lieu of:

    perl -e 'use Time::HiRes'

Comment: @mob : Thanks for the correction. @James_R_Ferguson : I purposely left out the `-M` flag because I didn't want to confuse the questioner with the syntax (using `1` instead of `''` is a nifty little tip though :).

Comment: @Zaid thanks!  is the value returned by calling time in milliseconds?

Comment: @JJLiu : It's the time in seconds since Jan 1, 1970 (aka the epoch)