# How can I display the current date and time, including microseconds?

Tags: perl, datetime

I need to display the date in the following format in one of my programs:

```
day - month - year "HH:MM:SS". <microseconds>
```

I am using Perl 5.8 and I have tried using epoch seconds and converting the time to microseconds like this:

```
my $epoch = time();
my $time1 = ($epoch - int($epoch)) *1e6
```

But I am getting this output:

```
25-05-2016 18:20:20.<incorrect number>
```

Comment: Use Time::HiRes to get microseconds:  http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html

Comment: HH:MM:SS.<microseconds>

Comment: @ruby Sorry, I see it now. The editor was stripping `<microseconds>` because it thought it was an HTML tag. In the future, please format your input, output, and code as I've done above to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: Any example for TimeHires which i can refer as i tried using gettimeofday() but it did not work

Comment: @ruby https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes

Comment: @ruby, seems to provide the solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997819/get-time-in-milliseconds-without-an-installing-an-extra-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get what you want,

```
use POSIX       qw( strftime );
use Time::HiRes qw( time );

my $epoch = time();
my $microsecs = ($epoch - int($epoch)) *1e6;

say strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime($epoch)) . "." . sprintf("%06.0f", $microsecs);
```

Output:

```
25-05-2016 10:50:01.088676
```

`sprintf` is used to pad and round to the nearest microsecond.

---

Alternative:

```
use POSIX       qw( strftime );
use Time::HiRes qw( gettimeofday );

my ($epoch, $microsecs) = gettimeofday();

say strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", localtime($epoch)) . "." . sprintf("%06d", $microsecs);
```

Comment: my $epoch = time();
my $microsecs = ($epoch - int($epoch)) *1e6; 
my $finaltime = sprintf("%s.%.0f",POSIX::strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",localtime(time),$microsecs)

It prints finaltime as 2016-05-25 13:20:20.146167500000 (microseonds value is too long and i want upto 6 digits only )

Comment: Thank you for your help. I saw reply late :(

Answer (score 5):

Use [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html)

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                             

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw( time );
use DateTime;

for (1..3) {
    my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time() );
    print $dt->strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%6N") . "\n";
    sleep 1;
}
```

Output:

```
25-05-2016 17:42:16.411722
25-05-2016 17:42:17.414295
25-05-2016 17:42:18.415920
```